# Pygame object moves to all sides except downwards

Tags: python, pygame

I'm learning to develop a  pygame using a book with an example. So basically I'm using a code from the book, the only thing I swapped was an element, which in my case is a robot.
In a word, I am supposed to make the robot move left, right, down and up -  and it does move to all the sides but won't move downwards. Again I copied the code from the example so it is supposed to work but it doesn't. Can anyone help? I am using classes here, so the main game code looks like this:

I am using classes here, so the main game code looks like this:

```
import sys

import pygame

from pygame import*

from pygame.locals import*

from settings import Settings

from robot import Robot

class Game:
    " " "Overall class to manage game assets and behavior." " "

    def __init__(self):
        " " "Initialize the game and create game resources." " "
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,\
        self.settings.screen_height), RESIZABLE)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket game")
        self.robot = Robot(self)

        #Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)


    def run_game(self):
         " " "Start the main loop for the game." " "
         while True:
                self._check_events()
                self.robot.update()
                self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        " " "Respond to keypresses and mouse events" " "
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit() 
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
                

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        " " "Respond to keypresses " " "
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.robot.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.robot.moving_left = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.robot.moving_up = True
        elif event_key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.robot.moving_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
          
            
    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        " " "Respond to key releases" " "
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.robot.moving_right = False
        elif event_key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.robot.moving_left = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.robot.moving_up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: 
            self.robot.moving_down = False
            

    def _update_screen(self):
        " " "Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen" " "
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.robot.blitme()
    
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Make a game instance and run the game.
    robot_game = Game()
    robot_game.run_game()
```

and the Robot class code is following:

```
import pygame

class Robot:
    " " "A class to manage Robot" " "

    def __init__(self, robot_game):
        self.screen = robot_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = robot_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = robot_game.settings


        #Load the ship image and get it's rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/robot.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Start each new robot at the chosen location on the screen
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center

        #Store a decimal value for the robot's horizontal position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        #Store a decimal value for the robot's vertical position.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        #Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        " " "Update the robot's position based on the movement flag" " "
        #Update the robot's value not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.robot_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.robot_speed
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.y -= self.settings.robot_speed
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom <= self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.y += self.settings.robot_speed

        #Update rect object from self.x.
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y



    def blitme(self):
         " " "Draw the robot at its current location." " "
         self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

and I've also got the Settings class:

```
class Settings:
    " " "A class to store all settings for Game." " "


    def __init__(self):
        " " "Initialize the game's settings." " "
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 1000
        self.bg_color = (0, 0, 0)

        #Ship settings
        self.robot_speed = 2
```

Comment: Typo: `event_key ` -> `event.key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `_check_keydown_events` there is the following line:

```py
elif event_key == pygame.K_DOWN:
```

However, the `event_key`variable doesn't exist. It should be `event.key`, as you want to get the attribute from the `event` variable.

Comment: Typo only questions should not be answered, but closed

Comment: @The_spider,wow! That is such a stupid mistake, a simple typo!!!! Too focused on the main body so I missed the symbol significance. Thank you so much!